# Why do I need to cast a character for an Integer variable but not for an int?

Tags: java, casting

What is the reason why I needed to cast the character to an int type here:

```
Integer integer= (int) 'a';
```

But I did not need to cast here:

```
int i='a';
```

Comment: Because you can only autobox an 'int' to an 'Integer'.

Comment: one is a primitive type and the another not.as above say you can only autobox an 'int' to an 'Integer'

Comment: Have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: @EJP Just curious, but why can I do the opposite: `Character c = 97;`?

Comment: the reason you can do the opposite is because Characters are composed of numbers...for example, the number 65 is the 'A' character...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [Java Language Specification 5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> Boxing conversion converts expressions of primitive type to corresponding expressions of reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> From type boolean to type Boolean
>
> From type byte to type Byte
>
> From type short to type Short
>
> From type char to type Character
>
> From type int to type Integer
>
> From type long to type Long
>
> From type float to type Float
>
> From type double to type Double
>
> From the null type to the null type

This rule is necessary because the conditional operator (§15.25) applies boxing conversion to the types of its operands, and uses the result in further calculations.

Comment: Long L=(long) 50;
here I need to cast 50 to long type because 50 is of type int and int to Long autoboxing is not allowed .........am I correct if not correct me.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 'int' (primitive type) is different from Integer (object type), so when you cast you first transform 'a' to an int type and then to an Integer type (a variable from int type is accepted by an Integer object)

Answer (score 1):

There are several types that can hold "integer" values (from mathematics point of view): `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`. The difference among them is only the number of bytes they occupy in memory, i.e max and min values.

All them are *primitives*. Smaller primitive can be assigned to corresponding higher one without casting.

Type `char` is almost the same as `short`. It stores code of corresponding unicode character. Therefore literal `a` is represents actually the code of character `a` and therefore can be assigned to any integer type. However once it is assigned to `char` variable it is actually just a code and therefore can be assigned then to `int` without casting.

Types like `Integer`, `Long`, `Short`, `Character` are actually primitive wrappers: they are regular classes that wrap primitives. Prior to java 5 you cannot write:

```
Integer ii = 5;
```

You had to write

```
Integer ii = Integer.intValue(5);
```

Java 5 introduced *autoboxing*: feature that does this magic for you. This means that literal `5` is just replaced by line like `Integer.intValue(5)` at compile time.

So, literal `a` is replaced by `Character.charValue('a')`. This experession returns type `Character` that definitely cannot be assigned to `Integer` variable. Casting to `int` solves it: in this case the literal `a` is transformed to type `int`, then transformed to `Integer` by autoboxing and therefor can be assigned to `Intger` variable.

Answer (score 0):

this is basic types and reference types Difference.
basic types JVM can automatic conversion the type,
but reference types you must manual conversion.